# I can't prerender pages that are not in getStaticPaths with fallback=true Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, use-context, prerender

I have a dynamic page which works well for pages which are in `getstaticpaths`'s params. The fall back is set to **true** and I want to check if the url is not defined. Then I want to get data from the **usecontext** and render those.

But, it shows an error. It doesn't even log the "it's empty" in the useEffect condition:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "../../styles/coffe_store.module.css";
import Image from "next/image";
import cls from "classnames";
import { fetchCoffeeStores } from "../../lib/coffe-stores";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "../_app";
import { isEmpty } from "../../utils";

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const coffeeStore = await fetchCoffeeStores();
  const findCoffeeStoreById = coffeeStore.find((cafe) => {
    return cafe.properties.place_id == params.url;
  });
  return {
    props: {
      store: findCoffeeStoreById ? findCoffeeStoreById : {},
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const coffeeStore = await fetchCoffeeStores();
  const paths = coffeeStore.map((store) => {
    return {
      params: { url: store.properties.place_id },
    };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}

const CoffeeStore = (initialProps) => {
  const route = useRouter();
  if (route.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  const url = route.query.url;
  const [coffeeStore, setCoffeeStore] = useState(initialProps.store || {});
  const {
    state: { coffeeStores },
  } = useContext(StoreContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialProps == {}) {
      console.log("it's empty");
      if (coffeeStores.length > 0) {
        const findCoffeeStoreById = coffeeStores.find((cafe) => {
          return cafe.properties.place_id == url;
        });
        setCoffeeStore(findCoffeeStoreById);
      }
    }
  }, [url]);

  console.log(coffeeStore);

  const handleUpvoteButton = () => console.log("handle upvote");
  return (
    <div className={styles.layout}>
      <Head>
        <title>{coffeeStore.properties.name}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.col1}>
          <div className={styles.backToHomeLink}>
            <Link href="/">
              <a> back to home</a>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.nameWrapper}>
            <h1 className={styles.name}>{coffeeStore.properties.name}</h1>
          </div>
          <Image
            src={
              coffeeStore.imgUrl ||
              " http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1529676468696-f3a47aba7d5d%3Fcrop%3Dentropy%26cs%3Dtinysrgb%26fit%3Dmax%26fm%3Djpg%26ixid%3DMnwzMzI2MzF8MHwxfHNlYXJjaHwxMnx8Y29mZmVlJTIwc2hvcHxlbnwwfDF8fHwxNjUzNzk3MzIy%26ixlib%3Drb-1.2.1%26q%3D80%26w%3D400&w=640&q=75"
            }
            width={600}
            height={360}
            className={styles.storeImg}
            alt={coffeeStore.properties.name}
          />
        </div>

        <div className={cls("glass", styles.col2)}>
          <div className={styles.iconWrapper}>
            <Image
              src="/assets/icons/map location.png"
              width={24}
              height={24}
            />
            <p className={styles.text}>
              {coffeeStore.properties.address_line2}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.iconWrapper}>
            <Image
              src="/assets/icons/paper_plane_1.png"
              width={24}
              height={24}
            />
            <p className={styles.text}>
              {coffeeStore.properties.address_line1}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.iconWrapper}>
            <Image src="/assets/icons/raiting.png" width={24} height={24} />
            <p className={styles.text}>1</p>
          </div>

          <button className={styles.upvoteButton} onClick={handleUpvoteButton}>
            upvote
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CoffeeStore;
```

Can somebody help me with how to fix this issue please.

Comment: The fact that `console.log("it's empty")` doesn't run simply means that `initialProps == {}` is never true. You're always passing a value in the `store` prop.

Comment: @juliomalves but even if i put the console.log outside of the if, still the whole useEffect never runs.